# Ansible Tower rest api job poll

Tags: rest, ansible-tower

Is there a way to fetch the job id for the execution of the job template through rest API?

Also, can we poll the job based on the job id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/api/v2/job_templates/<JT_ID>/jobs/` will give you all the jobs launched from that job template.  There area also a few convenience/summary fields in `/api/v2/job_templates/<JT_ID>/` to help you find the last job

You can then use this endpoint to monitor the job

`/api/v2/jobs/<JOB_ID>/stdout/`